# ¿Como aplicar estilos por jerarquía en divs anidadas?

Tags: css

En mi sitio web será muy común meter elementos *div* dentro de otros, como jerárquicamente. (ver imagen)

[image: Ejemplo en imagen]

En la imagen se puede apreciar lo que deseo:

- En el primer nivel de nodos (o sea, los nodos que no están dentro de otro), todos éstos tienen un mismo color (en este caso gris oscuro #DDD)
- el segundo nivel (los nodos que están dentro de los del primero), los nodos tienen color gris claro.
- al llegar al tercer nivel, los nodos vuelven a tomar el color de los del primero.

El código que usé para hacer el estilo de la imagen fue éste:

```
 body{background-color:#D5E5F9}
.a
  {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:1em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    background-color:#DDD;
  }
.a .a
{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
.a .a .a
{
    background-color:#DDD;
}
```

Pero es muy poco práctico ir poniendo `.a .a .a` como tonto cuantas veces llegue a ser necesario (podrían haber muchísimos niveles). Entonces intenté con los *nth-child*, así:

```
body{background-color:#D5E5F9}
.a
  {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:1em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    background-color:#DDD;
  }
.a:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

Pero el resultado fue éste:
[image: Ejemplo de lo que no busco]

Nada más alejado de lo que necesito.

Entonces bien, ¿cómo podría hacer esto de forma automática?

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente es una manera de realizarlo con **jQuery**, sería interesante ver si es posible solucionarlo utilizando **únicamente** **CSS** sin alterar el DOM

El algoritmo consiste en recorrer en profundidad el DOM a través de los hijos `<div>`, ignorando los elementos de otro tipo, agregándole la style class `even` u `odd` según corresponda (según su nivel de profundidad). Los elementos de nivel par tendrán un `background-color` y los de profunidad impar otro.

El algoritmo parte de las `div` que son hijas directas del `body`.

```js
let divTraversal = (currentDiv, level) => {
      // si es un nivel par se agrega la clase even-level
      if(level % 2 === 0){
          $(currentDiv).addClass("even-level");
      }else{
          // si es un nivel impar se le agrega la clase odd-level
          $(currentDiv).addClass("odd-level");
      }
      // se obtiene los hijos de la div que se esta procesando, para cada hijo se invoca la llamada recursiva 
      // con el mismo nivel
      const currentLevel = level + 1;
      $(currentDiv).children("div").each(function(){
         divTraversal(this, currentLevel);
      });
      // cuando no hay mas hijos por procesar culmina la llamada recursiva
};
 
 // obtener las divs hijas inmediatas de body, divs "raices"
 // para cada div raíz recorrer en profundidad 
 $("body > div").each(function(){
   divTraversal(this, 0)
 });
```

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
 }

.even-level{
    background-color:#DDD;
}

.odd-level{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
    
p{
    background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div>
      Nivel 1
     <div> Nivel 2
        <p> No soy un div ignorame! </p>
        <div>
           Nivel 3
        </div>
        <div>
            Nivel 3
             <p> No soy un div ignorame! </p>
            <div>
              Nivel 4
            </div>
            <div>
             Nivel 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            Nivel 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div> 
        Nivel 2
    </div>
    <div>
         Nivel 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      Nivel 1
  </div>
  <div>
      Nivel 1
      <div>
          Nivel 2
      </div>
      <div>
          Nivel 2
      </div>
      <div>
         Nivel 2
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      Nivel 1
  </div>
</body>
```